# How to insert data into SQL Server database and retrieve it and put into datagridview?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

What I want to do is, after you insert data into the SQL Server database, datagridview will retrieve the added data from database and add it in its row.

I'm new to vb.net

Code in my dialog add form. I name it dlgAdd

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class dlgAdd
    Dim ConStr As String = "Data Source=SERVER008;Initial Catalog=CollectionDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd1234"
    Dim sql As String
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK_Button.Click    
        sql = "insert into dataCollection(CustomerName,OR_no,SOR_no,Balance,Cash_Amount,Check_Amount) values('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtOR.Text & "','" & txtSOR.Text & "','" & txtBalance.Text & "','" & txtCash.Text & "','" & txtCheck.Text & "')"
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon)
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cancel_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel_Button.Click
        Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dlgAdd_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        sqlCon = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
        sqlCon.Open()
    End Sub
End Class

' here is my code in MainTrans form

dgMainData is my datagridview.

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frmMainTrans
    Dim ConStr As String = "Data Source=SERVER008;Initial Catalog=CollectionDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd1234"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM dataCollection"
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqlAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sqlDataset As DataSet
    Dim sqlTable As DataTable
    Private Sub Getdata()
        sqlCon = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
        sqlCon.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon)
        sqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        sqlBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter)
        sqlDataset = New DataSet
        sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDataset, "dataCollection")
        sqlTable = sqlDataset.Tables("datacollection")
        sqlCon.Close()
        dgMainData.DataSource = sqlDataset.Tables("dataCollection")
        dgMainData.ReadOnly = True
        dgMainData.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        dlgAdd.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub frmMainTrans_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call Getdata()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around.  The data entered into the dialgoue should be added to the `DataTable` that's bound to the grid first.  You would then use a data adapter to save that change from the `DataTable` back to the database, just as you would for edits and deletions.  In fact, you'd normally let the user make all the changes they want first and then save the lot in a single batch.

Comment: You need to google for tutorial

Comment: thanks for the tips. im having a hard time with this. im from vb6.0 and jump to vb.net. . thats why im confuse with my codes. maybe ill just google it